# How to correctly end subprocess in python?

Tags: python, subprocess

Can someone please clarify what is the most correct way to end the subprocess started with Popen?

Considering for example

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["tail", "-f", filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I found plenty of options:

```
proc.stdout.close()
proc.kill()
proc.terminate()
os.kill(proc, signal.SIGKILL)
os.kill(proc, signal.SIGINT)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) Popen supports `with` statements. So my guess is to use that, so it is made automatically. If you want I guess you can look inside the code to see what is done.

```
with subprocess.Popen(["tail", "-f", filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
    # do stuff
# everything should be closed now
```